# WebClient: (System.Net.WebException) Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.ios, webrequest

This is a MonoTouch application. I see errors out in the field with this exception. I see other SO quesitons, but nothing seems to be solving my issue. Could this be related to maxRequestLength on the server, or executionTimeout? I really have NO ideas...

I am not using a WebRequest, i'm using a WebClient. Please Help!

**STACK TRACE**

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.ReadAll (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileCore (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.String fileName, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Client Code (Monotouch)**

```
    public void UploadVideo(Guid organizationId, string path) {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password)));
        var authHeader = string.Format("Basic {0}", token);
        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        var resource = string.Format("/organizations/{0}/SyncVideo/", organizationId);

        var fi = new FileInfo(path);            
        wc.UploadFile(restClient.BaseUrl + resource, "POST", path);
        wc.Dispose();            
    }
```

**Server Code (ASP.Net MVC3)**

```
[HttpPost, Url("v3/organizations/{organizationId?}/SyncVideo/")]
public virtual JsonResult SyncVideo(HttpPostedFileBase file, Guid? organizationId) {
    if (organizationId.IsNull()) throw new HttpNotFoundExecption();
    if (organizationId != RESTContext.OrganizationId) throw new HttpNotAuthorizedException();

    var basePath = RESTContext.Config.VideoPath;

    using (new Impersonator(RESTContext.Config.VideoPathUsername, RESTContext.Config.VideoPathDomain,
        RESTContext.Config.VideoPathPassword)) {
        if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
        file.SaveAs(basePath + @"\" + file.FileName);
    }
    return JsonSuccess();
}
```

Comment: Is the file being uploaded to the server? Does the server return a response?

Comment: One word: Wireshark. Few words: It seems to fail after uploading (unless it aborted?) and the exception details should have more clues. In any case Wireshark would show you everything.